# before submit a form atleast one checkboxes is required

Tags: magento-1.7, checkbox

I have shown multiple check boxes,when I submit need atleast one checkbox is required., i tried below code.,

```
$fieldset->addField('checkboxes', 'checkboxes', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('listings')->__('Select Categories'),
            'name'      => 'cat_ids[]',
            'values'    => $categorieslist,
            'onclick'   => "",
            'onchange'  => "",
            'value'  => $cat_ids,
            'disabled' => true,
            'class' => 'category_match_to_listing',
            'required' => true,
        ));
```

even class name also not displayed in html

```
<input type="checkbox" value="14" name="cat_ids[]" id="checkboxes_id">
```

if i get one value `'values'    => 'single',` required field working fine,then the html is

```
<input type="checkbox" value="0" class="category_match_to_listing required-entry" name="cat_ids[]" id="checkboxes_id">
```

when I get dynamic it doesn't work., please suggest any ideas?

Comment: Why are you passing `cat_ids[]` to the `name` parameter?

Comment: passing multiple checkbox value

Answer (score 7):

Replace your code with this code

```
$fieldset->addField('checkboxes', 'checkboxes', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('listings')->__('Select Categories'),
        'name'      => 'cat_ids[]',
        'values'    => $categorieslist,
        'onclick'   => "",
        'onchange'  => "",
        'value'  => $cat_ids,
        'disabled' => true,
        'class' => 'category_match_to_listing validate-one-required',
        'required' => true,
    ));
```

Comment: You can also use validate-one-required-by-name method

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the `class` attribute like this:

```
'class' => 'category_match_to_listing validate-one-required-by-name',
```

Comment: I tried that Even though I didn't get class attribute in O/P.,

Answer (score 3):

To Select atleast one checkbox try below code

```
<input type="checkbox" value="14" class="validate-one-required" name="cat_ids[]" id="checkboxes_id" />
```

it worked for me..

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your issue is with `$cat_ids`. What happens when you `var_dump($cat_ids)` when getting your error? Does it return null or a string, rather than an array?

I'd suspect you're passing a non-array with `'value'  => $cat_ids` which is creating the problem.

If that's the case, you can try something like:

```
if (!is_array($cat_ids)) (array) $cat_ids;
```

Or, a bit easier to read:

```
if ( !is_array($cat_ids)) { // if $cat_ids is NOT an array
    $cat_ids = array($cat_ids); // turn it into an array
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question, I use `'required' => true` but it doesn't shown in frontend

Comment: I haven't had my coffee yet... but considering a checkbox is a boolean, using 'required' isn't going to work. You'll need some code to validate all the boxes, making sure at least one is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<input type="checkbox" value="0" class="category_match_to_listing required-entry" name="cat_ids[]" id="checkboxes_id">
```

With

```
<input type="checkbox" value="0" class="category_match_to_listing validate-one-required-by-name" name="cat_ids[]" id="checkboxes_id">
```